# How to track and show mouse position in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a questions with Unity 3d:  How do you get the current mouse position on a Canvas object in Unity 3D? Currently I'm trying to create a mouse tracker on the Unity 3D, so if you move the mouse on the canvas, there will be a small text below the mouse showing the current position of the mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting mouse position in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998241/getting-mouse-position-in-unity)

Comment: Are you need mouse position in canvas space, or in screen space?

Answer (score 1):

You can get mouse position from Input class
for complete example

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TrackMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;
    //get reference to the RectTransform component
    private RectTransform rectTransform;

    void Start ()
    {
        rectTransform = text.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        //Set the anchor to Left Below Corner
        rectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0,0);
        rectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(0,0);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        //update the position of the text
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D = Input.mousePosition;
        //display position info on the text
        text.text = Input.mousePosition.ToString();
    }
}
```