# Move the mouse pointer in a specific direction with unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mouse

I want to move the mouse pointer with something like: mouseposition += new Vector2(x, y).
The "GetCursorPos" is always (0, 0), so I can't move the mouse pointer with a delta value, but I can move it to a certain coordinate with SetCursorPos. I tryed the followong code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class all : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 MoveMouse;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Vector2 pos);

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 cursorPos = new Vector2();
        GetCursorPos(out cursorPos);
        //finding the cursor's position

        SetCursorPos(Mathf.RoundToInt(cursorPos.x + MoveMouse.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(cursorPos.y + MoveMouse.y));
        //cursorpos += MoveMouse
    }
}
```

I tryed another code where I replaced the GetCursorPos with another value, but the mouse pointer is moving randomly a bit when I moving it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class all : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
    public Vector2 offset;
    bool started;
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(waiting());
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (started)
        {
            SetCursorPos(Mathf.RoundToInt(Input.mousePosition.x + offset.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(-(Input.mousePosition.y + offset.y)));
        }
    }
    IEnumerator waiting()
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;
        SetCursorPos(0, 0);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        offset = new Vector2(-Input.mousePosition.x, -Input.mousePosition.y);
        started = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answers puts it really well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999239/13460353 I hope this helps.

Comment: I want the mouse's position in windows coordinate system, or translate the mouse. That answer uses input.mouseposition, and screentoworldpoint, the two things are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new input system (install via packagemanager) you can use
Mouse.current.WarpCursorPosition(...) (Input System version 1.0.0 as of nov 2020, or alternatively 1.1.0 preview 2).

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Mouse.html:

*On desktop platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux, and UWP), you can move the mouse cursor via code. Note that this moves the system's actual mouse cursor, not just Unity's internally-stored mouse position. This means that the user sees the cursor jumping to a different position, which is generally considered to be bad UX practice. It's advisable to only do this if the cursor is hidden (see the Cursor API documentation for more information).*

Answer (score 0):

So I had to do it myself

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class MouseControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePosition lpMousePosition);

    public int xdmp;
    public int ydmp;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MousePosition
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            xdmp = 0;
            ydmp = 0;
        }

        MousePosition mp;
        GetCursorPos(out mp);

        print(mp.x + " " + mp.y);

        SetCursorPos(mp.x + xdmp, mp.y + ydmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the same, but I seems I cannot access the SetCursorPosition/GetCursorPosition functions. What do I need to do in order to access them

Comment: It only works on windows.
You have to refer to a value as output: " 
MousePosition mp;
GetCursorPos(out mp);
"
If you are outside this class, then you have to use:"
  MouseControl.MousePosition mp;
       MouseControl.GetCursorPos(out mp);
"