# Instantiate a cube relative to mouse position in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My question is: Instantiate a cube relative to mouse position in unity like in minecraft placing a block relative to mouse position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting mouse position in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998241/getting-mouse-position-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

Well the best approach is going to depend on how you want to place the object relative to the camera. The solution I have found to work well in the past is Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you may then want to raycast along the camera's Z axis starting at the returned point to get the final position to place the object at.

Comment: I could not get it to work it would just spawn on top of the players head

Comment: Well that is pretty much the expected behavior, you would need to apply an offset to have it appear in front of the character. You could either use the z axis of the camera to statically position it forward or use  a ray cast to align it with other objects in the space.