# i am making a raycast from the cursor plz help unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a ray cast from the Cursor PLZ HELP
this is unity 3d
iv looked every where got nothing
btw the camera it standing still its not a movent camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Unity Docs for this. It is built in functionality

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

You can get the cursor position by using Input.mousePosition.x and Input.mousePosition.y

Also take a look at this question
[Getting mouse position in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998241/getting-mouse-position-in-unity)

Comment: what about the z ax's its a 3d game

Comment: You decide how far from the camera you want to start

Comment: and BTW is there a way to do it as a raycast

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html)

Beware that, as adviced in the docs:
1.- Ensure an Event System exists in the Scene to allow click detection
2.- For click detection on non-UI GameObjects, ensure a PhysicsRaycaster is attached to the Camera

There is a very simple example in the documentation which you can try to implement and once you make it work, adapt or extend that to your needs.